# link_rewrite is empty - Edit Product - Prestashop Webservice REST

Tags: python, xml, web-services, prestashop

I'm trying to edit a product via Prestashop Webservice.

I'm using Python 3 and generating my all XML, instead of using the PHP solution.

When I PUT my XML to edit the product, I receive an error

```
{"errors":[
    {"code":84,
    "message":"Validation error: \"Property Product->link_rewrite is empty\""}]}
```

the XML I'm sending is:

```
<prestashop>
    <product>
        <id>273481</id>
        <price>35.20</price>
        <wholesale_price>19.33</wholesale_price>
    </product>
</prestashop>
```

Why i'm receiving this error? The link-rewrite field is filled in all my products.

Comment: Hi Andy, can you indicate the end of PUT request?

Comment: The end is the JSON above. I send the put request with the parameter output_format=JSON, then, I receive the result in this format. Without this parameter I receive the same answer, but in XML format.

Answer (score 1):

you need to send at least all required fields in request, not just separate fields that was changed, call `/api/products?schema=synopsis` to see required fields.

Also [here](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Using+the+PrestaShop+Web+Service) available also Python lib that works with Prestashop webservice, maybe it will helps you.

Comment: Unfortunately prestapyt (the Python lib) works just in Python 2.7. I'm using python 3.4. I think in a 'update' I shoudn't send all required fields, just the fields I'm updating. In an 'insert' I agree. But I will try your way.

Comment: With Prestashop Webservice you need to first get the object you want to update, changes its values and then send an update request with all fields completed otherwise forgotten fields will be updated as blank.